# How can I make a search box selection toggle open a box (div?) below it to display information I've compiled

Tags: javascript, html, css

On a page of my site, I want a searchbox that will enable visitors to type in the name of a US state or Canadian territory or province. Once the searchbox is populated with their choice, I want clicking on an icon next to their selection to toggle open a box underneath that will display information I've compiled related to that selection.

Here, originally from CodeNepal, modified somewhat by me, is a good example of what I want. However, instead of sending the visitor to a Google page whose search term matches the inputted selection, I want a corresponding box to toggle open.  I know that it's the "weblink" line that needs to change, but I'm not sure how to amend it to display/hide a div or something like that.

Note: I'm not sure if this is even pertinent, but rather than attempt to relate each of the 64 posssible selections to a database entry, I would hand write them out into divs with anchors or whatever.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="search-input">
     <a href="" target="_blank" hidden></a>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Type to search..">
     <div class="autocom-box">
       <!-- here list are inserted from javascript -->
     </div>
     <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
   </div>
 </div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body{
  background: #644bff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

::selection{
  color: #fff;
  background: #664AFF;
}

.wrapper{
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}

.wrapper .search-input{
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.search-input input{
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 60px 0 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.search-input.active input{
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.search-input .autocom-box{
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.search-input.active .autocom-box{
  padding: 10px 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.autocom-box li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search-input.active .autocom-box li{
  display: block;
}
.autocom-box li:hover{
  background: #efefef;
}

.search-input .icon{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #644bff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
let suggestions = [
    "Alabama",
    "Alaska",
    "Arizona",
    "Arkansas",
    "California",
    "Colorado",
    "Connecticut",
    "District of Columbia",
    "Delaware",
    "Florida",
    "Hawaii",
    "Idaho",
    "Illinois",
    "Indianar",
    "Iowa",
    "Kansas",
    "Kentucky",
    "Louisiana",
    "Maine",
    "Maryland",
    "Massachusetts",
    "Michigan",
    "Minnesota",
    "Mississippi",
    "Missouri",
    "Montana",
];


// getting all required elements
const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-input");
const inputBox = searchWrapper.querySelector("input");
const suggBox = searchWrapper.querySelector(".autocom-box");
const icon = searchWrapper.querySelector(".icon");
let linkTag = searchWrapper.querySelector("a");
let webLink;

// if user press any key and release
inputBox.onkeyup = (e)=>{
    let userData = e.target.value; //user enetered data
    let emptyArray = [];
    if(userData){
        icon.onclick = ()=>{
            webLink = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${userData}`;
            linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
            linkTag.click();
        }
        emptyArray = suggestions.filter((data)=>{
            //filtering array value and user characters to lowercase and return only those words which are start with user enetered chars
            return data.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(userData.toLocaleLowerCase());
        });
        emptyArray = emptyArray.map((data)=>{
            // passing return data inside li tag
            return data = `<li>${data}</li>`;
        });
        searchWrapper.classList.add("active"); //show autocomplete box
        showSuggestions(emptyArray);
        let allList = suggBox.querySelectorAll("li");
        for (let i = 0; i < allList.length; i++) {
            //adding onclick attribute in all li tag
            allList[i].setAttribute("onclick", "select(this)");
        }
    }else{
        searchWrapper.classList.remove("active"); //hide autocomplete box
    }
}

function select(element){
    let selectData = element.textContent;
    inputBox.value = selectData;
    icon.onclick = ()=>{
        webLink = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${selectData}`;
        linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
        linkTag.click();
    }
    searchWrapper.classList.remove("active");
}

function showSuggestions(list){
    let listData;
    if(!list.length){
        userValue = inputBox.value;
        listData = `<li>${userValue}</li>`;
    }else{
      listData = list.join('');
    }
    suggBox.innerHTML = listData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dropdown with searchable text

```js
// hardcoded array - (you can fetch it from api aswell)
let suggestions = [
  "Alabama",
  "Alaska",
  "Arizona",
  "Arkansas",
  "California",
  "Colorado",
  "Connecticut",
  "District of Columbia",
  "Delaware",
  "Florida",
  "Hawaii",
  "Idaho",
  "Illinois",
  "Indianar",
  "Iowa",
  "Kansas",
  "Kentucky",
  "Louisiana",
  "Maine",
  "Maryland",
  "Massachusetts",
  "Michigan",
  "Minnesota",
  "Mississippi",
  "Missouri",
  "Montana",
];
const dropdownList = document.getElementById('statesList');

suggestions.forEach((suggestion, index) => {
  let el = document.createElement("option");
  el.label = suggestion;
  el.value = suggestion;
  el.id = suggestion;
  dropdownList.appendChild(el);
});

const search = () => {
  const selectedOption = document.getElementById('states').value;
  console.log(selectedOption);
  // inputVal is the selected option
  // write code to append data about selected option
  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Dropdown with searchable text</h1>
<form>
    <label for="states">Choose your state:</label>
    <input list="statesList" id="states" name="states" placeholder="type here..." />
  <button type='button' onclick='search()'>SEARCH</button>
    <datalist id="statesList"></datalist>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is on the right track. How can the info show up in a box rather than a console.log space at the bottom of the page (nicer for UI)? Also, if someone mistypes an option, it still returns a result.